# Share point 2013 on premise-How to configure js link after upload into site assets folder in list web part

Tags: 2013, custom-list, jslink

SharePoint 2013 on premise: How  to configure js link file after uploading into site assets folder in  list web part.

In list web part settings, in JS link I have configured:

> ~siteName/SiteAssets/foldername/scripts/filename.js

This is not working. I am trying to hide few columns to a specific group.

Comment: Can you please check in browser's developers tool(in newtwork section), the file you referenced is loaded or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you have placed your JS inside SiteAssets library of some CHILD site, you should use ~site/SiteAssets/ URL.

If you have placed your JS inside SiteAssets library of root site of the site collection, you should use ~sitecollection/SiteAssets//  URL.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37684.sharepoint-2013-jslink-client-side-rendering.aspx